Adding Fonts to Distroless Container for Jasper Reports in Java Application
I am working on a Spring boot application that utilizes Jasper Reports for generating PDF reports. However, I am facing an issue with fonts in my Distroless container. Distroless containers typically do not include fonts, and Jasper Reports requires fonts to be available in the system. How can I add fonts to a Distroless image to resolve this issue?
I have checked all previous posts about font and these solution talks about installing fonts in image which is not possible with distroless image.
Other Answers in posts:
All of the below posts are about docker image with distro and package manager. My question is about installing or using fonts in distroless image where we dont have any package manager.
Docker and Java - FontConfiguration issue - this solution is about alpine distro.
Docker and Spring boot giving "sun.awt.FontConfiguration.head" is null - RUN apk add can not be run inside distroless image.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463460/846536 - this does not look like a recommended solution.
Issue:
Without fonts I am getting following exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from short array because "sun.awt.FontConfiguration.head" is null
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:224)

or
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fontconfig head is null, check your fonts or fonts configuration
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1271)

I tried adding font with following method:
FROM myregistry:5000/xyz/builder-base:mytag as BUILDER
# ubuntu image with fonts in it
# do some stuff here, build artifacts
FROM myregistry:5000/xyz/mydistroless:mytag
# Copy app.jar
COPY --from=BUILDER /build/target/myapp.jar /opt/iamboss/app.jar
COPY --from=BUILDER /usr/share/fonts /usr/local/share/fonts
## Run my app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","app.jar"]


But the issue still persists.
Distroless images do not contain the package manager or shell, hence cannot run the fc-cache to update the cache. But this as per the reference i have shared, this won't be needed if fonts are available at /usr/local/share/fonts with permissions 644 (-rw-r--r--).
Is there any other way this can be done?
Reference:
Fonts in Debian

I am not sure why this question is deleted; all of the mentioned posts are not related to the question being asked. The question is about using fonts in distroless image. All other posts talked about installing fonts in docker image which is not possible with distroless image.

I agree with OP, this should not be closed as duplicate, as none of the linked questions are specific about distroless image.

given that this question is locked, I can't post an answer, but I found the workaround, by installing the fonts with package manager in a build stage, and copying the fonts over.
FROM debian:12.5 AS font-loader
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y fontconfig fonts-noto && \
    fc-cache -fv

FROM distroless

COPY --from=font-loader /usr/share/fonts /usr/share/fonts
COPY --from=font-loader /usr/share/fontconfig /usr/share/fontconfig
COPY --from=font-loader /etc/fonts /etc/fonts


@Joseph you can vote to reopen.
By the way I have already tried to use multi stage image with fonts and copy it to distroless, but it does not work for me, I'll try with your method and revert here.
