# Need help regarding an error in the Dockerized version of the application

Tags: java, docker, apache-poi

I am currently working on an application that uses a Spring Boot-based backend based on Java 17. I use Maven as the build tool. The front end is a ReactJS-based application.

In my developer environment, I use Oracle JDK java 17.0.4. When I build and execute the report functionality of this application it works as expected.

But when the same functionality is checked in a dockerized environment for one Excel report download scenario fails with an error. The back-end log indicates some errors briefly mentioned below.

***The error message encountered is a Java UnsatisfiedLinkError related to the libfontmanager.so library and its dependency libfreetype.so.6. This error seems to occur when Java is unable to load a required native library (libfreetype.so.6) that is necessary for the functioning of the Java font system.***

How can I resolve this issue on Docker environments? Are any changes required for the docker file or Java version used?

**Related docker File**

```
# === Stage 1: Build the Spring Boot app ===
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src/ /app/src/
RUN mvn package -DskipTests
# === Stage 2: Create the final Docker image ===
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
# Set environment variables for MySQL configuration
ENV MYSQL_HOST=localhost
ENV MYSQL_PORT=****** //Omitted
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=db
ENV MYSQL_USERNAME=****** //Omitted
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=************ //Omitted
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

**Brief set error messages are listed below.**

**2023-10-05T07:19:23.875Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/openjdk-17/lib/libfontmanager.so: Error loading shared library libfreetype.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/openjdk-17/lib/libfontmanager.so)] with root cause**

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/openjdk-17/lib/libfontmanager.so: Error loading shared library libfreetype.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/openjdk-17/lib/libfontmanager.so)**

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:310) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:280) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2392) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:808) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:57) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.<clinit>(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(SunFontManager.java:270) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(SunFontManager.java:268) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<clinit>(SunFontManager.java:268) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:82) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:526) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2279) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:469) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:530) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(SheetUtil.java:285) ~[poi-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:259) ~[poi-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:244) ~[poi-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:523) ~[poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:505) ~[poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at com.antarctica21.backend.forecasting.service.PlanService.saveWOSRZipExcelFile(PlanService.java:3352) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.antarctica21.backend.forecasting.service.PlanService.getWeekOversSalesExcelDetails(PlanService.java:3244) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager**

```
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:82) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:526) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2279) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:469) ~[na:na]
at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:530) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(SheetUtil.java:285) ~[poi-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:259) ~[poi-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:244) ~[poi-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:523) ~[poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:505) ~[poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
at com.antarctica21.backend.forecasting.service.PlanService.saveWOSRZipExcelFile(PlanService.java:3352) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.antarctica21.backend.forecasting.service.PlanService.getWeekOversSalesExcelDetails(PlanService.java:3244) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.antarctica21.backend.forecasting.service.PlanService.getWeekOversSalesExcelDetilsByCriteria(PlanService.java:541) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
at com.antarctica21.backend.forecasting.service.PlanService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getWeekOversSalesExcelDetilsByCriteria(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.antarctica21.backend.forecasting.controller.PlanController.getWeekOversSalesExcelDetilsByCriteria(PlanController.java:190) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
```

**Update on Issue**
Updated the docker file to handle the error identified due to Openjdk image limitation as suggested in below mentioned comments

To install the required packages (freetype and fontconfig) the Dockerfile was updated as  follows:

```
# Install required libraries
    RUN apk add --no-cache freetype fontconfig
```

I also updated the Apache POI dependencies to the latest versions as suggested.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update on Issue 2**
When the above-mentioned updates were made to the Docker file, the existing error was fixed but another issue was displayed due to font-related limitations.

java. lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from short array because "sun.awt.FontConfiguration.head" is null.

Updated the Docker file as mentioned below and the were resolved.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig
RUN update-ms-fonts
```

Comment: Unrelated, but never store database credentials in a docker image. Anyone can then see the plaintext values when you push to a Docker Registry

Comment: Thanks. I will change these details asap.

Some additional findings related to this question 

In spring docs they use eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine although it's an example of "a basic dockerfile", maybe it helps.

https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: The base image used is over a year old and contains lots of vulnerabilities and may be missing some libraries. Apparently, the OpenJDK base image isn't maintained for half a year. Maybe changing to Eclipse or Amazoncorretto would be an option.

Either find a base image that contains those missing font libraries or add it to your dockerfile as a step, eg apt-get install or yum install, so that it’ll be installed during packaging.

Comment: The Spring tutorial uses `eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine` instead of `eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine` but it could be due to the fact that the JRE image was not available when the tutorial was published: see this [blog post](https://adoptium.net/blog/2021/10/jlink-to-produce-own-runtime/).  If you have just *to run* a Java app, a JRE image is the best choice because it is smaller.

Comment: @Gehan, have you tried to install one of the packages suggested below?  Was `freetype`   enough or did you need the whole `fontconfig`?  Your feedback could be useful to other people.  If one of the answers solved your problem, remember to approve it.

Comment: The Dockerfile itself is unrelated to the error. Spring tutorials dont use Apache POI, which is the root of your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the above comments by @OneCricketeer and @Pino I
updated the docker file to handle the error identified due to Openjdk image limitation.

To install the required packages (freetype and fontconfig) the Dockerfile was updated as  follows:

```
 # Install required libraries
        RUN apk add --no-cache freetype fontconfig
```

I also updated the Apache POI dependencies to the latest versions as suggested by @OneCricketeer

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

When the above-mentioned updates were made to the Docker file and pom.xml, the existing error was fixed but another issue was displayed due to the same font-related limitation.

```
java. lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from short array because "sun.awt.FontConfiguration.head" is null.
```

I updated the Docker file as mentioned below and they were resolved.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig
RUN update-ms-fonts
```

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74975762/docker-and-spring-boot-giving-sun-awt-fontconfiguration-head-is-null)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=libfreetype.so.6&path=&name=&branch=v3.18&arch=x86_64), to install `libfreetype.so.6` in Alpine you need the `freetype` package:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache freetype
```

I would also change the base image: `openjdk:17-alpine` belongs to the [`openjdk`](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) repository that is deprecated, furthermore your `Dockerfile` suggests that a JRE image is enough for you.  You can use [`eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) or the smaller but unofficial [`pnavato/amazoncorretto-jre:17-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/r/pnavato/amazoncorretto-jre).

Comment: fontconfig seems to depend on freetype

Comment: Yes, confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on searching your error, you need to install a font package into the container.

Since Docker isn't a Desktop environment, the JDK doesn't need this for GUI related applications, such as handling Excel files and fonts within them

For example, on Debian/Ubuntu image

```
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1
```

Or on Alpine

```
RUN apk add --no-cache fontconfig
```

Also, the POI version you're using is 2+ years old, before Java 17 was released. Maybe upgrade and there's a fix available by now