docker container poi excel generation throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
Have async code to generate excel report using apache poi and at some line of code, below error is thrown, it dint give me more details on what line is causing the issue. Also this issue is only with the @Async methods, other methods without Async is generating Excel fine.
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ReportingActionAsynch {
    //Apache poi code to generate excel report
}


ERROR [pool-9-thread-1] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler
o.s.a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException(SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:39)

POST|/report/generateReport|||||||||||||--|Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void
com.action.ReportingActionAsynch.run(com.reporting.model.ReportingModel,com.dao.ReportingDAO,com.action.ReportingAction,com.action.DeckReportAction,com.models.LoginModelBean):
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
/opt/jdk/17.0_10l64/lib/libfontmanager.so: libfreetype.so.6: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory at
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method) at
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(Na...


I have added below entries in pom.xml, but this dint help
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <reportsDirectory>target/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <argLine>--add-opens
                java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/jdk.internal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.nio.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.util.stream=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.util.regex=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
                java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I see the "/opt/jdk/17.0_10l64/lib/libfontmanager.so" file but not the "libfreetype.so.6", i cannot install naything in the server, it is maintained by org. SO what should i ask them to install?
Docker info
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.9 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.9"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"


Looks like it can't read fonts from a file? java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk/17.0_10l64/lib/libfontmanager.so: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

@Chrimle "libfontmanager.so" file is available in the path "/opt/jdk/17.0_10l64/lib/"

But it's not finding libfreetype.so? Could this question be of interest?

Does this answer your question? Where is libfreetype.so.6 in OpenJDK, I got an unsatisfiedLinkError when using a kaptcha jar

@Chrimle Actually this is the solution may work for me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74978195/4910936 but the issue is "apk: command not found"
