Spring Boot - Fontconfig head is null error
I'm using a spring boot 3.3.x project and we need to create big excel files with apache poi and we are using the approach with the SXSSFWorkbook.
The docker image is built with the spring boot maven plugin
While creating the Excel file I have the error

Fontconfig head is null, check your fonts or fonts configuration

The same error is raised when this code is executed
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String[] fontNames = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fontNames));

How can I solve this issue? If possible I would continue to use the spring boot maven plugin

This might be of assistance -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74975762/docker-and-spring-boot-giving-sun-awt-fontconfiguration-head-is-null. You are running in docker so you probably will need to install fonts into your docker image.
